# I have 2 DCs, RF is 3 in both of them and consistency is set to quorum. What will happen when a read/write request comes and one of the DC is down?

Tags: cassandra

I have 2 DCs, RF is 3 in both of them and consistency is set to quorum. What will happen when a read/write request comes and one of the DC is down ?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `QUORUM`, then you need to have 4 servers with replica's online.  So in your case, if one DC is down, operations will fail. If possible, consider use of `LOCAL_QUORUM` instead.